# postgres how to properly use max function

Tags: postgresql

Help please with correct usage of max, I have the following:

```
select busqueda.valorBusqueda, count(*) from busqueda where usu_id = 24 group by busqueda.valorBusqueda;
```

and it works, but I want only the max count of it, so far I tried:

```
select max (busqueda.valorBusqueda, count(*) from busqueda where usu_id = 24 group by busqueda.valorBusqueda);
```

but no success..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution here is probably to use a `LIMIT` query:

```
select valorBusqueda, count(*) as cnt
from busqueda
where usu_id = 24
group by valorBusqueda
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Postgres does not support ties with `LIMIT`, but we can use the `RANK` analytic function here if you do want all ties for the highest count:

```
with cte as (
    select valorBusqueda, count(*) as cnt, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
    from busqueda
    where usu_id = 24
    group by valorBusqueda
)

select valorBusqueda, cnt
from cnt
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: First approach solves my problem, thank you very much man, not understanding very well second way, it returns me the max count yes, which is 3 and then a 1, what does it means? its returning valorBusqueda HAMBURGER, cte record (HAMBURGER,3, 1)

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast The second query is returning all records which have a #1 rank in their count...which would be one or more records tied with the highest count.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `subquery`.

```
select max(t.ct) from (
    select busqueda.valorBusqueda, count(*) ct from busqueda 
    where usu_id = 24 group by busqueda.valorBusqueda) t;
```

Comment: I like this approach and also solves my problem, thanks alot :)